# About the layout of a GUI

Tags: java, swing, layout

I'm in the middle of working on a program. It's GUI has two main parts, the left of the JFrame and the right of the JFrame. (Currently the right half is blank because I havn't started working on it yet).

The left part doesn't look good. All the buttons and textfields are stretched. I want them to have the height of standard buttons, similiar to the ones on this site. (You know, standard windows buttons).

How do I do that?

(I wouldn't want to simply pack() the whole thing, since the right half of the window is going to have a big square JPanel, and so pack()ing would mean that the window will still be square and the buttons on the left half would still be streched up and down).

Here's a picture:

[image]

And here's the code so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Event.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

    JButton rect,oval,tri,free,addPoint;
    JLabel xLabel,yLabel;
    JTextField xTextField,yTextField;
    JPanel leftPanel,rightPanel,optionsPanel,pointsPanel;

    public GUI(){
        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI(){

        setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,5,5));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Graphics Generator");
        setSize(500,500);

        rect = new JButton("Rectangle");
        oval = new JButton("Oval");
        tri = new JButton("Triangle");
        free = new JButton("Free Shape");
        addPoint = new JButton("Add point");

        xLabel = new JLabel("X: ");
        yLabel = new JLabel("Y: ");

        xTextField = new JTextField(2);
        yTextField = new JTextField(2);

        leftPanel = new JPanel();
        rightPanel = new JPanel();
        optionsPanel = new JPanel();
        pointsPanel = new JPanel();

        add(leftPanel);
        add(rightPanel);

        leftPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1,5,5));
        leftPanel.add(optionsPanel);

        optionsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4,2,2));

        optionsPanel.add(rect);
        optionsPanel.add(oval);
        optionsPanel.add(tri);
        optionsPanel.add(free);

        leftPanel.add(pointsPanel);

        pointsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,5,2,2));

        pointsPanel.add(xLabel);
        pointsPanel.add(xTextField);
        pointsPanel.add(yLabel);
        pointsPanel.add(yTextField);
        pointsPanel.add(addPoint);

        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GUI gui = new GUI();

    }

}
```

Comment: Perhaps the problem is with the layout you have chosen. Try using different layouts and check the results?

Comment: You should add a sketch on how you'd like the finished gui to look. Just a wireframe sketch, nothing fancy.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through following link for more information about Grid layout

[How to Use GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

Also try with different layouts in java swing

[A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this


import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Event.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

    JButton rect,oval,tri,free,addPoint;
    JLabel xLabel,yLabel;
    JTextField xTextField,yTextField;
    JPanel leftPanel,rightPanel,optionsPanel,pointsPanel;

    public GUI(){
        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI(){

        setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,5,5));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Graphics Generator");
        setSize(500,500);

        rect = new JButton("Rectangle");
        oval = new JButton("Oval");
        tri = new JButton("Triangle");
        free = new JButton("Free Shape");
        addPoint = new JButton("Add point");

        JPnel p=new JPanel();
p.add(rect);
p.add(oval);
p.add(tri);
p.add(free);
p.add(addPoint);
        xLabel = new JLabel("X: ");
        yLabel = new JLabel("Y: ");

        xTextField = new JTextField(2);
        yTextField = new JTextField(2);

        leftPanel = new JPanel();
        rightPanel = new JPanel();
        optionsPanel = new JPanel();
        pointsPanel = new JPanel();

        add(leftPanel);
        add(rightPanel);

        leftPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1,5,5));
        leftPanel.add(optionsPanel);

        optionsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4,2,2));

        optionsPanel.add(p);
        //optionsPanel.add(oval);
        //optionsPanel.add(tri);
        //optionsPanel.add(free);

        leftPanel.add(pointsPanel);

        pointsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,5,2,2));

        pointsPanel.add(xLabel);
        pointsPanel.add(xTextField);
        pointsPanel.add(yLabel);
        pointsPanel.add(yTextField);
        pointsPanel.add(addPoint);

        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GUI gui = new GUI();

    }

}


Like this for JLabels and JTextFields
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try [FlowLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) it is suitable for your requirement.

Just change `setLayout(new FlowLayout());`

Output :

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

You have that effect, because you use `GridLayout`, which resize component to whole cell(vertically/horizontally). You need to use another [`LayoutManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html), or combinations of layouts.

For example I've changed your code with [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html):

```
 private void initUI(){

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Graphics Generator");
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    rect = new JButton("Rectangle");
    oval = new JButton("Oval");
    tri = new JButton("Triangle");
    free = new JButton("Free Shape");
    addPoint = new JButton("Add point");

    xLabel = new JLabel("X: ");
    yLabel = new JLabel("Y: ");

    xTextField = new JTextField(2);
    yTextField = new JTextField(2);

    leftPanel = new JPanel();
    leftPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
    rightPanel = new JPanel();
    rightPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
    optionsPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    pointsPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints cMain = new GridBagConstraints();
    cMain.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    cMain.gridx = 0;
    cMain.gridy = 0;
    cMain.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    add(leftPanel,cMain);
    cMain.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    cMain.gridx++;
    cMain.weighty = 1;
    cMain.weightx = 1;
    add(rightPanel,cMain);

    leftPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    leftPanel.add(optionsPanel,c);
    c.gridy++;
    leftPanel.add(pointsPanel,c);

    c.gridy = 0;
    optionsPanel.add(rect,c);
    c.gridx++;
    optionsPanel.add(oval,c);
    c.gridx++;
    optionsPanel.add(tri,c);
    c.gridx++;
    optionsPanel.add(free,c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    pointsPanel.add(xLabel,c);
    c.gridx++;
    pointsPanel.add(xTextField,c);
    c.gridx++;
    pointsPanel.add(yLabel,c);
    c.gridx++;
    pointsPanel.add(yTextField,c);
    c.gridx++;
    pointsPanel.add(addPoint,c);

    setSize(500,500);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

[image]